# MixItUp pagination buttons not showing up

Tags: jquery, pagination, mixitup

The filtering and sorting work buttons work perfectly but I cannot get my pagination buttons to even show up. I'm using MixItUp.

```
 $(function(){
    $('#Container').mixItUp({
        controls: {
            enable: true
        },
        pagination: {
            limit: 1
        }
    })
 })
```

I have included the empty pager list div and followed all the other necessary steps.

```
<div class="pager-list">
    <!-- Pagination buttons will be generated here -->
</div>
```

Here is an example of my checkboxes that I am using for filtering.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="" value=".{{ brand.title }}" data-filter=".{{ brand.title | capitalize }}"><label>{{ brand.title }}</label>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the *jquery.mixitup-pagination.js* file?

The MixitUp Pagination is a premium extension you need to buy, so this part of MixitUp won't work unless you bought it and included it after the MixitUp script.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.mixitup-pagination.js"></script>
```